# Proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{n^{n+1}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{n^{n+1}}=0$$

I noticed that it can be expressed in the form of $n+1$ terms product but I have no idea with the upper bound.

I have trouble with how to operate $(-1)^n$

Comment: Note that $a_n\to 0$ if and only if $|a_n|\to0$, so you can get rid of the $-1$ immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us ignore the $(-1)^n$ for the time being

$$0<\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n^{n+1}}=\dfrac{n+1}n\cdot \prod_{r=2}^n\dfrac rn\cdot\dfrac1n<\dfrac{n+1}n\cdot\dfrac1n$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{n^{n+1}}$. Then, 
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+2}}(n+2)=\frac{1}{(1+\frac 1n)^n}\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\xrightarrow{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{e}<1.$$

Hence, $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|(-1)^n\right| = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left|-1\right|^n = \lim_{n\to \infty}1^n = \lim_{n\to \infty}1 = 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n = 1$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)!}{n^{n+1}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}} = \frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n}{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}} =\frac{\mathrm{finite}}{\infty} = 0$$